# How to delete OTP user input on Backspace key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've coded a OTP component but it has two issues that I couldn't solve.

The first issue is, when I press Backspace I want to delete the input value and then go to the previous input field to delete it.

The second issue is, when I delete a input (i.e the 3rd box) my code makes me focus on the next input field.

How can I implement Backspace key press properly and go to the previous input field when a input is deleted?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import css from '../components/css/OTP.css'
const Axios = require('axios')

const OTP = () => {
const [otp, setOtp] = useState(new Array(4).fill(""));

const handleChange = (element, index) => {
    if (isNaN(element.value)) return false;

    setOtp([...otp.map((d, idx) => (idx === index ? element.value : d))]);

    //Focus next input
    if (element.nextSibling) {
        element.nextSibling.focus();
    }
}

//eğer girilen OTP backendden gelen OTP ile aynıysa matchleştiğini göster ve kullanıcıyı verifike et daha sonra dashboarda aktar.

const checkOTP = async () =>{
try
{
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/auth/otp"
    const response = await Axios.post(url , {otp} , {withCredentials: true})

if(response.status!==200){
    alert("Invalid OTP entry") 
}
else{
    alert("OTP successful!")
}
}
catch(err)
{
console.log(err)
}
}

return (
    <>   
    <div className="otp-window">
        <div className="otp-modal"> 
        <div className="row">
            <div className="info">
                <p className="otp-info">Please enter the OTP sent to your email</p>
                
                {otp.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <input
                            className="otp-field"
                            type="text"
                            name="otp"
                            maxLength="1"
                            key={index}
                            value={data}
                            onChange={e => handleChange(e.target, index)}
                            onFocus={e => e.target.select()}
                        />
                    );
                })}

                <p className="otp-entered">OTP : {otp.join("")}</p>
                <p>
                    <button
                        className="clear-button"
                        onClick={e => setOtp([...otp.map(v => "")])}
                    >
                        Clear
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className="verify-button"
                        onClick={e =>
                            alert("Entered OTP is " + otp.join(""))
                        }
                     onClick={checkOTP}>
                        Verify OTP
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  
    </>
);
};
export default OTP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `input` event and check the `event.inputType` property of the `event` object like this. You might have to change the `onChange` prop to `onInput` though.

```
if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward' && event.target.value === '') {
  // Focus on the previous field
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind, can you please explain how can I detect Backspace key press and change the input box value to empty also?

Comment: You can detect a Backspace keypress with the `keydown` event by checking the `event.key` or `event.code` property of the `KeyboardEvent` object. For React, you would have to use the `onKeydown` prop

Comment: if (event.code === 'Backspace') {
    event.target.value = '';
  }